# OS-X: Web Sharing disabled, still 8 httpd processes

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, apache-http-server

I'm trying to find out why my MAMP Pro server is so notoriously slow and the first thing i did was taking a look at the activity monitor. It showed alot of httpd processes so I quit MAMP Pro and half of them disappeared which is fine, they should. But the other half keeps running, even when i've disabled websharing in the sharing preferences of OSX.

Anyone has an idea how to prevent OSX from running httpd by default even though i have web sharing off?

I'm running snow leopard on a MBP 64bit. All the remaining httpd processes run as _www, one runs as root.

Answer (score 1):

They may not be web sharing related.  For example, if you have printer sharing turned on there's a web page to check the [printer status](http://localhost:631/) on port 631.  more info on ports used by Apple software http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1629